# Pandas Series from Column with Column names

Tags: python, pandas

I like to get a new Series from a column containing column names, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col':['a','b','c','c','a','a'], 'a': [20,10,5,1,1,10], 'b': [4,10,5,2,10,12], 'c': [20,20,15,4,8,19]})

>>> df

  Col   a   b   c
0   a   20  4   20
1   b   10  10  20
2   c   5   5   15
3   c   1   2   4
4   a   1   10  8
5   a   10  12  19
```

I need a Series from this that shows for each row of "Col" the value in the column:

```
>>> s

0    20
1    10
2    15
3     4
4     1
5    10
dtype: int64
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `apply` over the dataframe.

```
In [339]: df.apply(lambda x: x[x['Col']], axis=1)
Out[339]:
0    20
1    10
2    15
3     4
4     1
5    10
dtype: int64
```